# After first run doesn't add "something" to EOF... How come?

Tags: java

The second time the word "something" should be add to the file and print "atext had been added" but it treats it as an empty file....

anything..

```java
public class ReadFile {
    public ReadFile() {
    }

    public boolean readFile() {
        boolean success = false;
        String file_name = "source/text.txt";

        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(file_name);

            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(file); 
            BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter (file_name));

            if (read.readLine() != null) {
                bf.append("something");
                System.out.println("a text has been added!!");
            } else {
                bf.append(file_name);
                System.out.println("File updated");
            }

            read.close();
            bf.close();
            success = true;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        return success;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
        rf.readFile();
    }
}
```

while the file is not empty "something" should be added to EOF

Comment: Did you open and see the file after the first run to see if "Something" got actually written to it ?

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised you can open a file for both reading and writing at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few changes needed here

- You need to open file in append mode for writing
- You need to call flush() after appending data to the file for it to be read
- You need a loop, at least if you want everything to happen in the same run

Note that I have used an infinite loop here which is dangerous so room for improvement there. I also added a println when catching exception

---

```
try {
    FileReader file = new FileReader(file_name);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(file); 
    BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter (file_name, true));

    while(true) {
        if(read.readLine() != null) {
            bf.append("something");
            System.out.println("a text has been added!!");
            break;
        } else {
            bf.append(file_name);
            bf.flush();            
            System.out.println("File updated");
        }
     }
     read.close();
     bf.close();
     success = true;

} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` That's an improvement, but shorter to type and more informative in action is `e.printStackTrace()` which will automatically print to the `System.err` stream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in append mode, otherwise it will be emptied when it is opened by FileWriter:

```
BufferedWriter bf = new 
                BufferedWriter(new FileWriter (file_name, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously writing to the same file you are trying to read from. Writing a file without append option truncates the file's content to zero length.
Try writing to a different file.

Comment: "Try writing to a different file" why? Writing to the same file seems to be a requirement in this case.

Comment: Looks like a bad idea for me, to read and write to/from the same file concurrently. I would never do this in my code.
Reading/Writing might become random based on the order of the operations and the buffer states - inside java and the operating system.
If I'd like to read and write from the same file, I'd rather use RandomAccessFile and make absolutely clear what I want to do.